# Way to prevent momentary "no Image Available" in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have this snippet

```
<b-img v-if="validPicture" :src="imgSrc" fluid alt></b-img>
  <b-embed v-else-if="validVideo" type="iframe" aspect="16by9" :src="imgSrc" allowfullscreen></b-embed>
  <p v-else >Sorry. No Image Available</p>
```

I would like it if the v-else "Sorry No image Available" does not do a FOUT like behavior before my image loads. v-cloak does not work for this. Any suggestions most welcome.

Updated code are:

```
          this.validPicure = /\.bmp|\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg\.tiff/gim.test(
            this.imgSrc
          );
          this.validVideo = /http/gim.test(this.imgSrc);
```

Computed Property:

```
computed: {
    noImage: function() {
      if (this.imgSrc === null || this.imgSrc === undefined) {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: try changing v-if to v-show

Comment: v-show does eliminate the FOUT effect but I need the conditional rendering power of v-if because API endpoint may send back a picture or an embedded video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the logic behind `validPicture` and `validVideo` but presumably you can augment that with a `noImage` computed property

```html
<b-img   v-if="validPicture" :src="imgSrc" fluid alt />
<b-embed v-else-if="validVideo" type="iframe" aspect="16by9" :src="imgSrc" allowfullscreen />
<p       v-else-if="noImage" >Sorry. No Image Available</p>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be `v-else` on the end?

Comment: What element(s) would you condition with `v-else`? Whatever you used would have the same problem of temporarily rendering before the image validity was established. The fragment above doesn't render anything until the validity is established. I _think_ that's the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check if is a valid picture and if the variable is not empty

```
<b-img v-if="validPicture && imgSrc !== '' && imgSrc !== undefined" :src="imgSrc" fluid alt></b-img>
```

Same with video

```
<b-embed v-else-if="validVideo && imgSrc !== '' && imgSrc !== undefined" type="iframe" aspect="16by9" :src="imgSrc" allowfullscreen />
```